# A Minipage Environment Where the Content is Left-Right Justified Except for the Last Line Which is Flushright

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage, paragraphs, justification

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Large

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}% 
\textbf{``The Bitterness of Poor Quality Remains Long After the Sweetness of Low Price is Forgotten.'' \emph{---Benjamin Franklin}}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{25pt}

\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}% 
\textbf{``The Bitterness of Poor Quality Remains Long After the Sweetness of Low Price is Forgotten.'' \\[3pt] \hfill \emph{---Benjamin Franklin}}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

Using the series of commands `\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%` renders the minipage content both left and right justified, save the last line which is centered---such as displayed in the first minipage output.

I would like the to happen for all lines in the minipage, except the last, which will contain a person's name---This I would like flughright.

I tried using `\\[3pt]` followed by `\hfill`, but as you can see in the second minipage output, this not only does not produce the objective, but also loses the centering of the line immediately prior.

*Remark:* Using either `\vspace{3pt}` or `\vspace*{3pt}` produces the same unwanted result. However, using the deprecated `\vskip 3pt` does, at least, center the second to last line instead of making it flushleft---though, it does not force the ---Benjamin Franklin over to the right.

It may not matter, but I compile the MWE code with `lualatex`, but I would like to be able to do such a thing also with code compiled with `pdflatex` as well.

QUESTION: How may the above code be modified so that I may display the main content as that produced by `\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%` but having the last line, i.e., "---PERSON'S NAME" displayed flushright?

Thank you.

Comment: just leave a blank line then \raggedleft then the name

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But adding just a blank line within the minipage produces for me an error---Paragraph ended before \text@command was complete.

Comment: No that is a paragraph inside `\textbf`  if you want it all including the name bold don't use `\textbf` use `\bfseries` with no braces.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah! that seems to be the ticket! Incidentally, a separate blank line seems not now to be needed---although the minipage environment now accepts it. Thank you.

Comment: yes it is, otherwise the preceding paragraph will be set ragged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want two paragraphs, one last line centred, one ragged left:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Large

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}
\bfseries

\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}% 
``The Bitterness of Poor Quality Remains Long After the Sweetness of
Low Price is Forgotten.''

\raggedleft
 \emph{---Benjamin Franklin}
\end{minipage}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for turning your most helpful comments into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you want to avoid having to type explicitly all those commands; in the future you may no longer like that rendering and…

The simple idea is to typeset the author name in a separate paragraph, flush right.

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\nicequote}{sO{5.75in}O{c}+mm}{%
  \IfBooleanF{#1}{\begin{center}}%
  \begin{minipage}{#2}[#3]
  \bfseries
  #4\par
  \raggedright---\mbox{\itshape #5}
  \end{minipage}
  \IfBooleanF{#1}{\end{center}}%
}
```

This way, `\nicequote*` would avoid `center` and allow you to place two quotations next to each other.

Examples.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\NewDocumentCommand{\nicequote}{sO{5.75in}O{c}+mm}{%
  \IfBooleanF{#1}{\begin{center}}%
  \begin{minipage}[#3]{#2}
  \bfseries
  #4\par
  \raggedleft\mbox{---\itshape #5}
  \end{minipage}
  \IfBooleanF{#1}{\end{center}}%
}

\begin{document}

\nicequote{
  ``The Bitterness of Poor Quality Remains Long After 
  the Sweetness of Low Price is Forgotten.''
}{Benjamin Franklin}

\nicequote[4in]{
  ``The Bitterness of Poor Quality Remains Long After 
  the Sweetness of Low Price is Forgotten.''
}{Benjamin Franklin}

\begin{center}
\nicequote*[3in]{
  ``The Bitterness of Poor Quality Remains Long After 
  the Sweetness of Low Price is Forgotten.''
}{Benjamin Franklin}\qquad
\nicequote*[2in]{
  ``The buck stops here''
}{Harry S Truman}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\nicequote*[3in][t]{
  ``The Bitterness of Poor Quality Remains Long After 
  the Sweetness of Low Price is Forgotten.''
}{Benjamin Franklin}\qquad
\nicequote*[2in][t]{
  ``The buck stops here''
}{Harry S Truman}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Possible improvement, with the “Bourbaki trick”

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\NewDocumentCommand{\nicequote}{sO{5.75in}O{c}+mm}{%
  \IfBooleanF{#1}{\begin{center}}%
  \begin{minipage}[#3]{#2}
  \bfseries
  #4%
  {\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50
  \qquad\mbox{}\nobreak\hfil\mbox{---\itshape #5}%
  \setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt}\finalhyphendemerits=0 \par}
  \end{minipage}
  \IfBooleanF{#1}{\end{center}}%
}

\begin{document}

\nicequote{
  ``The Bitterness of Poor Quality Remains Long After 
  the Sweetness of Low Price is Forgotten.''
}{Benjamin Franklin}

\nicequote[4in]{
  ``The Bitterness of Poor Quality Remains Long After 
  the Sweetness of Low Price is Forgotten.''
}{Benjamin Franklin}

\begin{center}
\nicequote*[3in]{
  ``The Bitterness of Poor Quality Remains Long After 
  the Sweetness of Low Price is Forgotten.''
}{Benjamin Franklin}\qquad
\nicequote*[2in]{
  ``The buck stops here''
}{Harry S Truman}
\end{center}

\begin{center}
\nicequote*[3in][t]{
  ``The Bitterness of Poor Quality Remains Long After 
  the Sweetness of Low Price is Forgotten.''
}{Benjamin Franklin}\qquad
\nicequote*[2in][t]{
  ``The buck stops here''
}{Harry S Truman}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]